# How to evaluate API response from server and act accordingly at client side using Fetch() and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, response

I fetch data at server side and push the result to global variable and then send that global variable to client with app.post method using Express.js. My problem is that client fetches the global variable too soon without the data received from the API first. How can I evaluate the response so that client would wait the global variable to reveive data first before displaying anything.

Server side, code looks something like this:

```
let sharpe = ''
app.post('/api', async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log('I got a request!')
  thisOne = req.body.stock1
  thisOne2 = req.body.stock2

  var result = await setup();

  res.json({
    status: 'success',
    stocks: sharpe
  });

})
```

Sharpe is the global variable storing the response from multiple API calls and is the one that should be sent back to client. Client side code is this:

```
  const sendData =  async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var stock1 = document.getElementById('weight1').value
    var stock2 = document.getElementById('weight2').value

    const data = {stock1, stock2};
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }

    fetch('/api', options).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {

      console.log(res.stocks);

    })
```

}

As a result SendData() function fetches the sharpe variable that is empty at the moment. How can I adjust client side code or server side code that the client waits for a correct response? Thanks.

One solution would be to store the API results to database and client would fetch ready made datastream but is there more straightforward solution?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your client does a fetch request to the server. Then receives the result inside the promise resolution. The global variable is Sharpe, and is sent to the client as the result. Please be more precise

Comment: Please give better details about the sharpe parameter. Currently, it is set to an empty string. Your example doesn't really reflect your described problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it starded working when I pushed all the API calls in the app.post middleware at the server side using promise chaining. The initial problem remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for your API Server to set the `sharpe` Parameter, it needs to be awaited, which you already did. It depends on the setup function (for example setup()) which fills the `sharpe` parameter. It has to return a promise, which is resolved once sharpe is filled with the data.

```
let sharpe = ''

async setup() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sharpe = 'test';
    // set value for sharpe
    resolve()
  })
}


app.post('/api', async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log('I got a request!')
  thisOne = req.body.stock1
  thisOne2 = req.body.stock2

  var result = await setup();

  res.json({
    status: 'success',
    stocks: sharpe
  });

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your example works the way it should! It seems that in my case three API calls that eventually fill the sharpe variable is just too slow and client throws empty string at first try. Only when the sendData function is called at the second time it works the way it should. Oh well, gotta figure some workaround